# syncfusion wpf sfdatagrid trouble scrolling

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I have problems with understanding syncfusion library for wpf. More specifically, it's about sfDataGrid control. This control in my app is inside standard WPF ScrollView control. So, the problem is, whenever I hover sfDataGrid, it takes scroll events and the scroll itself is not working. So what's the problem? What's the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SfDataGrid has its own ScrollViewer. So it is not recommended to load the SfDataGrid inside the ScrollViewer as it provides infinite size to its children which leads to lose of UI virtualization. While loading SfDataGrid inside ScrollViewer, the SfDataGrid’s ScollViewer gets disabled. However, you can overcome this by setting the height of SfDataGrid while loading inside the ScollViewer.

```
<ScrollViewer>
     <Syncfusion:SfDataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                            Height="600"
                            AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Source}" />        
</ScrollViewer>
```

-Thangapriya,Syncfusion Software.